# Ubuntu 20.04 > Ubuntu Studio Installer - audio package throws 'E; Unable to correct probnlems, you have held broken packages.'

Tags: package-management, 20.04, ubuntu-studio

Other packages have installed just fine. For some reason, this one will not work.

There is no terminal output, this is the Ubuntu Studio Installer GUI application. I tried running it from the command line and got not output there.

Screenshot from application:

[image: Screenshot from application]

Already done the following:

- Ran `apt update & upgrade & autoremove`:

  ```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  All packages are up to date.
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Calculating upgrade... Done
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  ```
- Ran `sudo apt update –fix-missing`:

  ```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  All packages are up to date.
  ```
- Ran `sudo dpkg –configure -a` → no results.
- Ran `sudo apt install -f`:

  ```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  ```
- Ran `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` → no results.
- I even installed Synaptic and ran fix errors in that a couple times for extra giggles.
- I thought it might be conflicting with the Ardour 6 version I had installed, uninstalled that and no change.

The error is completely unhelpful to me at this point and I don't know where it logs any additional information. If it even logs additional information.

Any thoughts on next steps?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having what looks like the same problem with the same results of running the commands in the question.

Comment: I got it working on my system.

In my case it was some conflict with `libavcodec-extra` (a dependency of `ubuntustudio-audio` and `ubuntustudio-vidio`) and `playonlinux` or something in its dependencies tree.

I didn't need it anymore so I removed `playonlinux` ran `sudo apt autoremove` and tried `ubuntustudio-installer` again and it seems to have worked fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I got it installed. I found thanks to the link below that a certain package was missing (`libavcodec-extra`).

To install this one I needed to install `libavcodec-extra58` and from there on all the broken packages were removed, after which I could finally install `ubuntustudio-audio`.

Reference:

- [Fixing broken packages UbuntuStudio](https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=22111)